# Finding voltage in series-parallel

Tags: voltage, parallel, series

I'm working my way into an Electronics Technician career diploma and have came across a question that is kind of throwing me for a loop.

[image: schematic and question]

I'm kind of confused on which resistors would be considered parallel.  I'm assuming the answer is 6V just as an educated guess but was hoping I could get some elaboration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R4 is in parallel to R2+R3. R2 and R3 are in series, but R4 and R2+R3 are both in series with R1.

Comment: Got it.  Not sure why I didn't see that earlier.

Comment: 2 downvotes, really? SMDH

Comment: Down votes because this is HWK and the reply did not explain why this is the case.

Comment: @Gonzik its obvious that it is homework and or a test question. OP didn't hide it, and had already chosen the correct answer, even if it was by elimination of improbable answers. I provided enough to answer OPs question, and provide further insight, while still leaving enough for the op to figure out themselves. They weren't asking for a thesis.

Answer (score 2):

Contrast to the other two answers, I think the most obvious way to answer this question is to simply use [KVL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff.27s_voltage_law_.28KVL.29). If the switch is closed, then you know the voltage across \$R_4\$ is the same as the voltage across \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$ (due to the definition of a wire in a schematic). This is confirmed by the given information (\$1.2V + 1.2V = 2.4V\$). Following this, you simply add the given voltage across \$R_1\$ and the resulting voltage *is* the voltage across the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, Forget about the switch S1. It's there to confuse you. Think about the general circuit. As Passerby said R4 is in parallel with R2+R3.

R4 || R2+R3 combined have volt drop of 2.4 V. So 2.4 V + 3.6 V gives you 6 V. So that battery voltage is 6 V.

Answer (score -1):

I hope, it would be helpful to you.
[image]

So answer is 6V.